# Delete inside JTextField does not work with a new BasicLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, look-and-feel

I was surprise to see that JTextField stopped responding to delete action if you apply a new (Basic)LookAndFeel for the application.

Bellow is the complete code for this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class App2 {
     private static final Logger log =  Logger.getLogger(App2.class.getCanonicalName());

     public static void main(String args[]){
         setUI();

         JFrame f = new JFrame();

         JTextField tf = new JTextField();
         f.add(tf);



         f.setSize(300, 300);
         f.setVisible(true);
           f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     }

  static void setUI(){
       try {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new DummyLookAndFeel());
       } catch ( UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
             log.warning("Setting UI not ok : " + ex.getMessage());
       }
   }
}

class DummyLookAndFeel extends BasicLookAndFeel {
     @Override
     protected void initComponentDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
         table.put("TextField.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));
     }

     @Override
     public String getName() {
         return "Just a fancy name";
     }

     @Override
     public String getID() {
         return "Something unique";
     }

     @Override
     public String getDescription() {
         return "A very very long description";
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

Any idea of why is happening?

Comment: *"stopped responding to delete action"* It seems to affect any control action apart from typing new text. Copy, paste, select all .. even moving the cursor backwards through the text with the 'left arrow'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if I change the initComponentDefaults(...) to

```
protected void initComponentDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
  super.initComponentDefaults(table);

  Object fim = table.get("TextField.focusInputMap");

  Object fieldInputMap = new UIDefaults.LazyInputMap(new Object[] {
                     "ctrl C", DefaultEditorKit.copyAction,
                     "ctrl V", DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction,
                     "ctrl X", DefaultEditorKit.cutAction,
                       "COPY", DefaultEditorKit.copyAction,
                      "PASTE", DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction,
                        "CUT", DefaultEditorKit.cutAction,
             "control INSERT", DefaultEditorKit.copyAction,
               "shift INSERT", DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction,
               "shift DELETE", DefaultEditorKit.cutAction,
                 "shift LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionBackwardAction,
              "shift KP_LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionBackwardAction,
                "shift RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionForwardAction,
             "shift KP_RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionForwardAction,
                  "ctrl LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.previousWordAction,
               "ctrl KP_LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.previousWordAction,
                 "ctrl RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.nextWordAction,
              "ctrl KP_RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.nextWordAction,
            "ctrl shift LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionPreviousWordAction,
         "ctrl shift KP_LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionPreviousWordAction,
           "ctrl shift RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionNextWordAction,
        "ctrl shift KP_RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.selectionNextWordAction,
                     "ctrl A", DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAction,
                       "HOME", DefaultEditorKit.beginLineAction,
                        "END", DefaultEditorKit.endLineAction,
                 "shift HOME", DefaultEditorKit.selectionBeginLineAction,
                  "shift END", DefaultEditorKit.selectionEndLineAction,
                 "BACK_SPACE", DefaultEditorKit.deletePrevCharAction,
           "shift BACK_SPACE", DefaultEditorKit.deletePrevCharAction,
                     "ctrl H", DefaultEditorKit.deletePrevCharAction,
                     "DELETE", DefaultEditorKit.deleteNextCharAction,
                "ctrl DELETE", DefaultEditorKit.deleteNextWordAction,
            "ctrl BACK_SPACE", DefaultEditorKit.deletePrevWordAction,
                      "RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.forwardAction,
                       "LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.backwardAction,
                   "KP_RIGHT", DefaultEditorKit.forwardAction,
                    "KP_LEFT", DefaultEditorKit.backwardAction,
                      "ENTER", JTextField.notifyAction,
            "ctrl BACK_SLASH", "unselect"/*DefaultEditorKit.unselectAction*/,
             "control shift O", "toggle-componentOrientation"/*DefaultEditorKit.toggleComponentOrientation*/
  });

  table.put("TextField.focusInputMap", fieldInputMap);


  table.put("TextField.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));
}
```

the JTextField seems to be working. It seems that UIDefaults has no entry for "TextField.focusInputMap" (In the example the fim Object is null)

Comment: I will wait a while to see if somebody can give a better solution / explanation.